# view does not recompose on flow value change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So I looked for a solution on StackOverflow and read the documentation to see if I was doing something wrong, but I could find out.

I have a list of activities that I fetch from Firestore and display in a `LazyColumn`. Every activity has a name of an image that I have to get its link from Firebase storage. After I get the link in my variable, **I expect the view (`AsyncImage`) to recompose as the variable is of type `StateFlow`, but nothing happens.**

In my repository file, the code for getting actitivities and the download URL of the image works fine.

In my `viewModel`, I have two functions to load the activities and the download URL:

```
viewModel((private val dataSource: ChadHubDigitDataSource): ViewModel() {
...
    var activities: LiveData<ActivityResponse>? = null
    private var _uri = MutableStateFlow<Uri>(Uri.parse(""))
    val uri: StateFlow<Uri>
        get() = _uri

    fun loadActivities() {
        activities = flow {
                emit(dataSource.getActivities())
            }.stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
            initialValue = ActivityResponse()
        )
    }

    fun loadImage(imageName: String) {
            _uri.value = dataSource.getImage(imageName)
    }
```

Bellow is the code in my compose function:

```
val activities = _eventsViewModel.activities?.collectAsState()?.value?.activity
LazyColumn {
    if (activities != null)
    {
        items(activities) { item ->
            Column(
                ...
            ) {
                // Loading the URL of the image
                _eventsViewModel.loadImage(item.img)
                Image(
                    ...
                    painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
                            ImageRequest.Builder(
                                LocalContext.current
                            )
                                .data(
                                data = _eventsViewModel.uri.collectAsState().value
                            )
                                .apply(
                                    block = fun ImageRequest.Builder.() {
                                        crossfade(false)
                                        placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                                        error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                                    }
                                ).build()
                        ),
                    ...
                )
                ...
    }
```

**When the activities are displayed, it's the error image that is displayed even after the value of the variable `uri` changed in the `viewModel`.**

Do you know a better way I can do such functionality or why my code is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your `ImageRequest.Builder` block of code, my `Firebase` Image fetching implementation stopped working, only showing the `placeholder` and not fetching.

```
 ImageRequest.Builder(context)
            .data(url)
            .apply (
                block = fun ImageRequest.Builder.() {
                    crossfade(false)
                    placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                }
            )
            .build()
```

Can you try doing it this way?

```
   ImageRequest.Builder(context)
            .data(url)
            .crossfade(false)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .build()
```

Comment: Thank you, this one is much better. Mine was a code suggested by Android Studio because my code was deprecated according to the IDE. I found that adding ```.allowHardware(false)``` to the builder in my initial code allow the image to be displayed, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Glad to know its working now :)